# How to find Sum of positive values and negative values separately in a column

Tags: sql, teradata

If there is a column number which has 5 rows as follows:

```
+----------+
|  values  |
+----------+
|   -2     |
|   -1     |
|    0     |
|    1     |
|    2     |
|    3     |
+----------+
```

I need the sum of all negative values and the sum of all positive values in my resultset.

Comment: What is your current approach?

Comment: Choose the structure of the result set. What whould it be, 2 columns or 2 rows?

Comment: RESULTSET IS TWO COLUMNS ONE SHOULD SHOW SUM OF POSITIVE VALUES AND OTHER SUM OF NEGATIVE VALUES

Answer (score 5):

The problem context is not clear. So, I'll assume this is about data stored in a RDBMS table. I'll also assume you want to use SQL language to get results.

suppose table is `DATA_TABLE` and column name which interests us is`VALUE` then, query should look like

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN VALUE > 0 THEN VALUE ELSE 0 END) POSITIVE_BALANCE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN VALUE < 0 THEN VALUE ELSE 0 END) NEGATIVE_BALANCE 
FROM DATA_TABLE;
```

If assumptions are incorrect, please edit your question with more details, context of the questions and programming environment where you want to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN col > 0 THEN col ELSE 0 END) AS posSum,
       SUM(CASE WHEN col < 0 THEN col ELSE 0 END) AS negSum
FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(values) FROM yourTable WHERE value <> 0 GROUP BY SIGN(values)
```

Edit:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM NUMBER_DATA WHERE value <> 0;

     VALUE
----------
         2
        -3
         4
         5
        -9
         1
         5
         7
        -8
        10
SQL> SELECT SIGN(VALUE), SUM(VALUE) FROM NUMBER_DATA WHERE value <> 0 GROUP BY SIGN(VALUE);

SIGN(VALUE) SUM(VALUE)
----------- ----------
          1         34
         -1        -20
```

Comment: Also, group by column `SIGN(values)` must be part of `SELECT` as well, otherwise how does one know which row is for sum of positives and which is sum of negatives?

Comment: SELECT SUM(_values),CASE WHEN SIGN(_values) = 1 THEN 'SUM' ELSE 'SUBTRACT' END FROM #yourTable GROUP BY SIGN(_values)

Comment: @VijayakumarUdupa: Hmmmm, let me guess, the sum of the negatives is *negative* and the sum of positives is *positiv*? :-)

Comment: @Mansoor, sign(0) is 0. You are going to get a 3rd row in you query.

Comment: @Dudu Markovitz,Just use where condition value <> 0

Answer (score 1):

I guess you'll need to combine tow queries in one like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(col) FROM my_table WHERE col > 0) as positive_val, 
(SELECT SUM(col) FROM my_table WHERE col < 0) as negative_val
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something real simple like this:

```
SLEECT * FROM
(SELECT SUM (VALUE) POS_SUM FROM TABLE WHERE VALUE > 0) A
JOIN 
(SELECT SUM (VALUE) NEG_SUM FROM TABLE WHERE VALUE < 0) B
ON 1 = 1;
```

Vijaykymar’s solution would also work.